# When is a nilpotent Lie algebra isomorphic to the associated graded of its lower central series?

Tags: lie-algebras, nilpotent-groups

All Lie algebras in this question are finite-dimensional and defined over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$ which I'm happy to take to be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

$\DeclareMathOperator\gr{gr}$Let $L$ be a nilpotent Lie algebra.  It is then filtered by its lower central series, and we have an associated graded nilpotent Lie algebra $\gr L$.  It is definitely not the case that $L$ and $\gr L$ have to be isomorphic; see [Malcev Lie algebra and associated graded Lie algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/q/122238/174957) for some examples.

Question: what kinds of conditions can I put on $L$ that ensure that it is isomorphic to $\gr L$?  E.g. if the field is $\mathbb{R}$ are the there geometric/topological/algebraic conditions on the associated simply-connected nilpotent Lie group that ensure this?

Comment: TeX note:  for correct spacing, use `\DeclareMathOperator`, as in $\DeclareMathOperator\gr{gr}$$\gr L$ `$\DeclareMathOperator\gr{gr}$$\gr L$` (or its one-shot version $\operatorname{gr} L$ `\operatorname{gr} L`) instead of $\text{gr} L$ `\text{gr} L`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice: Thanks, I did not know that!  I routinely use DeclareMathOperator when I'm writing papers, but didn't think of using it on MathOverflow.

Comment: I largely survey/elaborate about the description of finite-dimensional Carnot Lie algebra (= those isomorphic to their associated graded) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.5295) ("Gradings on Lie algebras, systolic growth, and cohopfian properties of nilpotent groups", Bull SMF 2016), see notably §3.2.

Comment: A sufficient condition, by the way, for $c$-step nilpotent $L$ to be Carnot, is that $L/L^c$ is that $L/L^c$ is free $(c-1)$-step nilpotent. This is, in particular, automatic if $c\le 2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator\gr{gr}$Too tired to think clearly, but it looks like a standard Deformation Theory thingy.

We have natural linear maps $\gamma_n (L)\rightarrow \gr_n L$. Split them as linear maps. We get a bijective linear map $L\rightarrow \gr L$.

Use it to equip $\gr L$ with a second Lie algebra structure $[,]^{\prime}$, coming from $L$. Now consider the difference
$$\mu:L\otimes L \rightarrow L, \ \ \mu (x\otimes y) = [x,y]-[x,y]^{\prime}.$$
I claim that $\mu$ is a 2-cocycle on $\gr L$ and that finding an isomorphism $\gamma_n (L)\cong \gr_n L$ is equivalent to finding a 1-cochain $\theta$ such that $\mu=d\theta$.

Comment: This doesn't seem in the spirit of the question, which asks for conditions on $L$ (not general cohomological obstructions).

Comment: $H^2=0$ is sufficient. Vanishing of a natural cohomology class is necessary and sufficient. Sorry, I am not good with spirits.

Comment: Is it possibly the case that given a finite-dimensional positively graded Lie algebra $G$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (the finite-dimensional and positively graded assumptions force $G$ to be nilpotent), the set of isomorphism classes of nilpotent Lie algebras with associated graded $G$ are in bijection with $H^2(G)$?  Maybe you have to talk about filtered Lie algebras with filtrations that aren't necessarily the LCS.  That would be a cool result.

Comment: @BugsBunny $H^2(L)=0$ for a finite-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebra over a field implies $\dim(L)\le 1$.

Comment: @YCor I did not know. That is depressing.

Comment: It's quite easy: assume that the Lie algebra $L$ is $c$-step nilpotent and has abelianization of rank $d\ge 2$. Write it as quotient $L=G/H$ of $G$ free $(c+1)$-step nilpotent of rank $d$. Let $J$ be an ideal in $G$ that has codimension 1 in $H$, $G'=G/J$, $H'=H/J$. Then $L=G'/H'$ and $H'$ has dimension 1; in addition by construction $H'\subset [G',G']$. So the central extension $0\to H'\to G'\to L\to 0$ defines a nonzero 2-cohomology class.

Comment: @Irina for your last question, this sounds like a quite random expectation; the 2-dimensional abelian Lie algebra is already a counterexample.

Comment: @YCor: I wasn't expressing an opinion as to the answer since I hadn't worked out any examples.  It was mostly an attempt to probe what Bugs Bunny was saying in his answer.  I have never thought about deformation theory, so I don't have strong intuitions for how this stuff should work.

Comment: Oh, by the way it seems this 2-cohomology class rather lies in $H^2(L,L)$ than $H^2(L)$. However, it's probably true that $H^2(L,L)$ is nonzero for every nilpotent Lie algebra of dimension $>1$ (in dimension $2,3,4,5,6,7$, it has dimension $=2$, $\ge 8$, $\ge 15$, $\ge 24$, $\ge 34$, $\ge 48$ by classification).

Comment: Yes, I meant with coefficients in the adjoint representation.

Comment: (Excuse me, I forgot what we were calling what.  My [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385925/when-is-a-nilpotent-lie-algebra-isomorphic-to-the-associated-graded-of-its-lower/386093#comment984260_386093) about conditions on $L$ was meant to refer to conditions on $\exp(L)$, which seems to be the goal of the question.  But of course it is up to @Irina to say what counts as an answer.  My point was sort of that the generality of this answer means that it's not really saying anything specifically about nilpotent algebras.)